# PowerApps - Hide fields from user who created the entry

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, sharepoint-fields, if-condition, hide

I have a PowerApps form connected to a SharePoint list.  In my form I'd like to have a bunch of fields that are visible to all, except the User who created the entry.  I only want that user to see a few columns, then when their manager goes into the form, they can see all of the other fields and act accordingly.  I have the Created By column from the SP list in my form.  Can I set the form so that certain fields are hidden from that particular User?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the fields you'd like to hide from the user who created the item, set the `Visible` property to

> ThisItem.'Created By'.Email <> User().Email

A slight improvement to this might be to use the formula above for one field and set the other fields to the visible property of the first field.

e.g. Set `Field1` visible property to

> ThisItem.'Created By'.Email <> User().Email

then set `Field2` and `Field3` visible property to

> Field1.Visible